# ProcessException: Process exited abnormally: xcrun: error: unable to find utility "xcodebuild", not a developer tool or in PATH flutter run

Tags: flutter, xcode

I am trying to run flutter run and I am getting this error message:
[image]

I'm aware that I have an older version of Xcode (Xcode 13.2). I can not install a newer version because my apple laptop is old

I tried running flutter run I was expecting the app to load and I got this error message